# How can I root cause DNS lookup failures in a (local) kubernetes instance (where sky-dns is healthy)

Tags: dns, kubernetes

It appears that local-up-cluster in kubernetes, on ubuntu, isn't able to resolve DNS queries when relying on cluster DNS.

**setup**

I'm running an ubuntu box, with environmental variables for DNS set in local-up-cluster:

```
# env  | grep KUBE
KUBE_ENABLE_CLUSTER_DNS=true
KUBE_DNS_SERVER_IP=172.17.0.1
```

**running information**

sky-dns seems happy:

`I0615 00:04:13.563037       1 server.go:198] Skydns metrics enabled (/metrics:10055)
I0615 00:04:13.563051       1 dns.go:147] Starting endpointsController
I0615 00:04:13.563054       1 dns.go:150] Starting serviceController
I0615 00:04:13.563125       1 logs.go:41] skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for tcp://0.0.0.0:10053 [rcache 0]
I0615 00:04:13.563141       1 logs.go:41] skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for udp://0.0.0.0:10053 [rcache 0]
I0615 00:04:13.589840       1 dns.go:264] New service: kubernetes
I0615 00:04:13.589971       1 dns.go:462] Added SRV record &{Host:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local. Port:443 Priority:10 Weight:10 Text: Mail:false Ttl:30 TargetStrip:0 Group: Key:}
I0615 00:04:14.063246       1 dns.go:171] Initialized services and endpoints from apiserver
I0615 00:04:14.063267       1 server.go:129] Setting up Healthz Handler (/readiness)
I0615 00:04:14.063274       1 server.go:134] Setting up cache handler (/cache)
I0615 00:04:14.063288       1 server.go:120] Status HTTP port 8081`

kube-proxy seems happy:

`I0615 00:03:53.448369    5706 proxier.go:864] Setting endpoints for "default/kubernetes:https" to [172.31.44.133:6443]
I0615 00:03:53.545124    5706 controller_utils.go:1001] Caches are synced for service config controller
I0615 00:03:53.545146    5706 config.go:210] Calling handler.OnServiceSynced()
I0615 00:03:53.545208    5706 proxier.go:979] Not syncing iptables until Services and Endpoints have been received from master
I0615 00:03:53.545125    5706 controller_utils.go:1001] Caches are synced for endpoints config controller
I0615 00:03:53.545224    5706 config.go:110] Calling handler.OnEndpointsSynced()
I0615 00:03:53.545274    5706 proxier.go:309] Adding new service port "default/kubernetes:https" at 10.0.0.1:443/TCP
I0615 00:03:53.545329    5706 proxier.go:991] Syncing iptables rules
I0615 00:03:53.993514    5706 proxier.go:991] Syncing iptables rules
I0615 00:03:54.008738    5706 bounded_frequency_runner.go:221] sync-runner: ran, next possible in 0s, periodic in 30s
I0615 00:04:24.008904    5706 proxier.go:991] Syncing iptables rules
I0615 00:04:24.023057    5706 bounded_frequency_runner.go:221] sync-runner: ran, next possible in 0s, periodic in 30s`

**result**

However, I don't seem to be able to resolve anything inside the cluster, same result with docker exec or kube exec:

```
➜  kubernetes git:(master) kc exec --namespace=kube-system kube-dns-2673147055-4j6wm -- nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Defaulting container name to kubedns.
Use 'kubectl describe pod/kube-dns-2673147055-4j6wm' to see all of the 
containers in this pod.
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve
nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local': Name does not resolve
```

**question**

Whats the simplest way to further debug a system created using local-up-cluster where the DNS pods are running, but kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local is not resolved ?  Note that all other aspects of this cluster appear to be working perfectly.

System info : Linux ip-172-31-44-133 4.4.0-1018-aws #27-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 19 17:20:58 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Example of resolv.conf that is being placed in my containers...

```
/etc/cfssl # cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 172.17.0.1
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local dc1.lan
options ndots:5
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on your post so I'll attempt to answer this.

First of all, certain Alpine images [have trouble resolving using nslookup](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/30215#issuecomment-246052589). DNS might in fact be working normally in your cluster.

To validate this, read the logs of the pods (eg. traefik, heapster, calico) that communicates with kube-apiserver. If no errors are observed, what you have is probably a non-problem.

If you want to be doubly-sure, deploy a non-Alpine pod and try `nslookup`.

If it really is a DNS issue, I will debug in this sequence.

1. `kubectl exec` into the kube-dns pod. Run `nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local localhost`. If this works, DNS is in fact running. If it doesn't, `kube-dns` should have entered a `CrashLoopbackOff` state by now.
2. `kubectl exec` into a deployed pod. Run `nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local <cluster-ip>`. If this works, you're good to go. If it doesn't, something is up with the pod network. Without details, I can't recommend further steps.

Bonne chance!

Comment: Hi Eugene: I indeed have tried more then one image and tried exec for the dns pods as well.  It's Definetely not working.

Comment: Does that mean `nslookup` in step no. 1 doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I figured I'd post a systematic answer that usually works for me.  I was hoping for something more elegant, and this isn't ideal, but I think its the best place to start.

1) Make sure your DNS nanny and your SkyDNS are running.  The nanny and Sky DNS should both show in their docker logs that they've bound to a port.

2) When you create new services, make sure that SkyDNS is writing them to the logs and showing the creation of SRV and so on.

3) Look in /etc/resolv.conf in your docker containers.  Make sure the nameserver looks like something on your internal docker IP addresses (i.e. 10.... in a regular docker0 config on fedora)

There are specific env variables you need to export correctly: API_HOST=true and KUBE_ENABLE_CLUSTER_DNS=true.

Theres alot of deeper tools you can use, like `route -n` and so on to debug container networking even more, but local up cluster should generally 'just work' and if the above steps surface something supsicious, its worth mentioning in the kubernetes community as a possible bug.